# Rotate background image height 100%

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to make my images responsive with some rotation angle (10deg) but my height is increasing too much, and it's not at center and full width.

**This is the design** (colors are background-image), as you can see, with the rotation, I can't fill all the top side and same with bottom, and another problem, is my full height increase.

[image: Structure]

***CSS: CODE**

```
.rotate > div {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
.rotate > div > div > div {
   transform: scale(1) rotate(10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
}
.full {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .list {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .item {
    height: 50%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the images within a pseudo element and allow some overflow to cover the white space:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 min-height:500px;
 height:100vh;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.box {
  height:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-40%;
  left:-10%;
  right:-10%;
  bottom:-40%;
  transform:rotate(-10deg);
  background:var(--i) center/cover no-repeat;
}
.box.first::before {
  bottom:0;
}
.box.last::before {
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box first" style="--i:url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=0)">

</div>
<div class="box last" style="--i:url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069)">

</div>
```

Comment: i see, but i want that the horizontal divition betwen the images has the rotation too

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña check the update, you need to move the overflow hidden to an upper element to see the rotation

Comment: by the way can u explain me a bit what does this -> --i: in style? thanks

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña it's CSS variable, I used it to simplify the code. Instead of writing a CSS for each image, I use only one using a varible then I simply change the variable for each element

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña you cannot, because it applies to the pseudo element and not to the element that's why I used variable ... I define the variable inside the main element using style then the pseudo element will inherit it

Comment: the only problem i saw here, is the images are not center, top image is aligned to bottom, and bottom image is aligned to top, is there some way to fix it on middle?

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña yes you can adjust background position for each one ... I keep it center but you can play with different values to obtain what you want.